# Facebook data source missing availability_circle_x column when adding XML source

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to add my products from my custom website to my Facebook catalog with a XML data source.

I've set all the needed columns in the XML file as so:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link>Link</link>
        <description>Product feed for Facebook catalog</description>
        <create_at>2024-03-20</create_at>
        <item>
            <id>614850830</id>
            <g:title xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">Réfrigérateur JBeaudoin 461845848</g:title>
            <g:description xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">Excepturi natus rerum ut mollitia et consequuntur. Dolores voluptates quia maxime consequatur dolor. Non est minus delectus aspernatur. Eaque recusandae tempora aperiam modi. Facilis recusandae veniam nostrum libero ea quisquam eos rerum.</g:description>
            <g:link xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">/produit/461845848</g:link>
            <g:image_link xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">/storage/product-images/no-image.png</g:image_link>
            <g:brand xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">Brand</g:brand>
            <g:condition xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">new</g:condition>
            <g:availability xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price xmlns:g="http://example.com/ns">114.99 CAD</g:price>
        </item>
    </rss>
```

But when Facebook is retriving the product, I get an error message that says that those fields are missing: `availability_circle_origin et availability_circle_radius, ou availability_polygon_coordinates, ou availability_postal_codes, ou availability_circle_radius and address`

Here's another [threads](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/289816597495613/) on Facebook blog, that talks about the same issue.

We can't find any documentation how to format those fields, any ideas?

Thanks!